# Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^(https|s3)://([^/]+)/?(.*)$

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am writing a notebook on amazon SageMaker studio. I follow the instructions given by the
instructor who is an amazon engineer. However, I am getting the following error.

```
%%sh
pip3 -q install --upgrade pip
pip3 -q install sagemaker awscli boto3 smdebug pandas matplotlib seaborn --upgrade

from IPython.core.display import HTML
HTML('<script>.jupyter.notebook.kernel.restart(</script>)')
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sagemaker
import boto3, os
from sagemaker.estimator import Estimator
from sagemaker.debugger import rule_configs, Rule, DebuggerHookConfig, CollectionConfig

!wget -N https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00222/bank-additional.zip'
!unzip -o bank-additional.zip'


!head ./bank-additional/bank-additional-full.csv

data = pd.read_csv('bank-additional/bank-additional-full.csv', sep=';')
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
data[:10]


data['no_previous_contact'] = np.where(data['pdays'], 1, 0)
data.drop(data['pdays'])
data['not_working'] = np.where(np.in1d(data['job'], ['student', 'retired', 'unemployed']), 1, 0)


model_data = pd.get_dummies(data)
model_data[:10]

train_data, validation_data, test_data = np.split(model_data.sample(frac=1, random_state=123), 
                                                 [int(0.7 * len(model_data)), int(0.9*len(model_data))])  

pd.concat([train_data['y_yes'], train_data.drop(['y_no', 'y_yes'], axis=1)], axis=1).to_csv('train.csv', index=False, header=False)
pd.concat([validation_data['y_yes'], validation_data.drop(['y_no', 'y_yes'], axis=1)], axis=1).to_csv('validation.csv', index=False, header=False)

test_data.drop(['y_no', 'y_yes'], axis=1).to_csv('test.csv', index=False, header=False)

bucket = sagemaker.Session().default_bucket()                     
prefix = 'sagemaker/DEMO-xgboost-dm'

boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(os.path.join(prefix, 'train/train.csv')).upload_file('train.csv')
boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(os.path.join(prefix, 'validation/validation.csv')).upload_file('validation.csv')
boto3.Session().resource('s3').Bucket(bucket).Object(os.path.join(prefix, 'test/test.csv')).upload_file('test.csv')


s3_input_train = sagemaker.TrainingInput(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/train'.format(bucket, prefix), content_type='csv')
s3_input_validation = sagemaker.TrainingInput(s3_data='s3://{}/{}/validation/'.format(bucket, prefix), content_type='csv')
s3_data = {'train': s3_input_train, 'validation': s3_input_validation}

sess = sagemaker.Session()
region = boto3.Session().region_name


container = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve('xgboost', region, version='latest')
save_interval = '1'

xgb = Estimator(  # The algorithm (XGBoost)
                  # IAM Permissions for SageMaker
                  # save the model here
    container,
    role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
    sagemaker_session=sess,
    input_mode='File',
    output_path='s3//{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix),
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.m4.2xlarge',
    use_spot_instances=True,
    max_run=300,
    max_weight=600,
    debugger_hook_config=DebuggerHookConfig(s3_output_path='s3//{}/{}/output'.format(bucket,
            prefix), collection_configs=[CollectionConfig(name='metrics'
            , parameters={'save_interval': str(save_interval)}),
            CollectionConfig(name='predictions',
            parameters={'save_interval': str(save_interval)})]),
    rules=[Rule.sagemaker(rule_configs.class_imbalance(),
            rule_parameters={'collection_names': 'metrics'})],
    )

xgb.set_hyperparameters(
objective='binary:logistic', 
eval_metric='auc', 
num_round=100, 
early_stopping_rounds=10)

xgb.fit(s3_data)
```

ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the CreateTrainingJob operation: 3 validation errors detected: Value 's3//sagemaker-us-west-2-034611191912/sagemaker/DEMO-xgboost-dm/output' at 'profilerConfig.s3OutputPath' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^(https|s3)://([^/]+)/?(.*)$; Value 's3//sagemaker-us-west-2-034611191912/sagemaker/DEMO-xgboost-dm/output' at 'debugHookConfig.s3OutputPath' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^(https|s3)://([^/]+)/?(.*)$; Value 's3//sagemaker-us-west-2-034611191912/sagemaker/DEMO-xgboost-dm/output' at 'outputDataConfig.s3OutputPath' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^(https|s3)://([^/]+)/?(.*)$

Comment: Is the regex error saying you need : ? Like s3:// , not s3// ...

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo - Search/Replace

```
s3//
```

With:

```
s3://
```